# eee pc 1025c shows black screen after booting on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

eee pc 1025c shows black screen after booting on Ubuntu 10.04

It does work in recovery mode, but not in default mode

Comment: solution: Open the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Search  for "vga=". It will be set to 790 or something like that.
Change vga= to 0x315
Save the file and reboot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Open the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Search  for "vga=". It will be set to 790 or something like that.
Change vga= to 0x315
Save the file and reboot
```

Comment: `vga=XXX` is not part of a default grub install http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/grub/trunk/grub/annotate/head:/docs/grub.cfg